# Not have to wait for if statement to run

Tags: stepper

I need some advice. I am trying to code a setup of 4 stepper motors that are connected to a keypad and 2 DC-motors that run a conveyor belt. My goal is to be able to push a key, the correspondning stepper motor starts and the DC-motors starts as well and run for a couple of seconds after the stepper. However, I want to be able to push multiple keys while the DC-motors are running. Right now I need to wait for the DC-motors to be done before I can push another key. How can I make this happen?

I think there will be issues if I code it with a timer since the keys are waiting for an input. I don't have any sensors.

This is my code:

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Stepper.h>

const int stepsPerRevolution = 1024;

Stepper myStepper1(stepsPerRevolution, 22, 26, 24, 28);
Stepper myStepper2(stepsPerRevolution, 32, 36, 34, 38);
Stepper myStepper3(stepsPerRevolution, 23, 27, 25, 29);
Stepper myStepper4(stepsPerRevolution, 33, 37, 35, 39);

const int IN1 = 47;
const int IN2 = 45;
const int IN3 = 51;
const int IN4 = 49;

const int ENA = 43;
const int ENB = 53;



const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //three columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'D','C','B','A'},
  {'H','G','F','E'},
  {'L','K','J','I'},
  {'P','O','N','M'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {2, 3, 4, 5}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {6, 7, 8, 9}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
   myStepper1.setSpeed(10);
   myStepper2.setSpeed(10);
   myStepper3.setSpeed(10);
   myStepper4.setSpeed(10);

  pinMode (IN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (IN2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (IN3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (IN4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (ENA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (ENB, OUTPUT);

}
  
void loop(){
 // char key = keypad.getKey();
 char key = keypad.waitForKey();


   if (key){
    Serial.println(key);
//control speed 
  analogWrite(ENA, 200);
  analogWrite(ENB, 200); 
//control direction 
int onTime   = 5000;
  digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);



 
// ----------------------------------Stepper1-----------------------------

        // just print the pressed key
   if (key == 'A' ){
    Serial.println(key);
     // step one revolution in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper1.step(256);
  delay(100);
}

  // just print the pressed key
   if (key == 'E' ){
    Serial.println(key);
     // step one revolution in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper1.step(512);
  delay(100);
}

  if (key == 'I' ){
    Serial.println(key);
     // step one revolution in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper1.step(768);
  delay(100);
  }

  if (key == 'M' ){
    Serial.println(key);
     // step one revolution in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper1.step(1024);
  delay(100);
  }


//-----------------------Stepper2------------------------

if (key == 'B' ){
    Serial.println(key);
     // step one revolution in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper2.step(256);
  delay(100);
}

  // just print the pressed key
   if (key == 'F' ){
    Serial.println(key);
     // step one revolution in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper2.step(512);
  delay(100);
}


  if (key == 'J' ){
    Serial.println(key);
     // step one revolution in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper2.step(768);
  delay(100);
  }


  if (key == 'N' ){
    Serial.println(key);
     // step one revolution in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper2.step(1024);
  delay(100);
  }


 //------------------------Stepper3--------------------

if (key == 'C' ){
    Serial.println(key);
     // step one revolution in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper3.step(256);
  delay(100);
}

  // just print the pressed key
   if (key == 'G' ){
    Serial.println(key);
     // step one revolution in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper3.step(512);
  delay(100);
}


  if (key == 'K' ){
    Serial.println(key);
     // step one revolution in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper3.step(768);
  delay(100);
  }


  if (key == 'O' ){
    Serial.println(key);
     // step one revolution in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper3.step(1024);
  delay(100);
  }

 //------------------------Stepper4--------------------

if (key == 'D' ){
    Serial.println(key);
     // step one revolution in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper4.step(256);
  delay(100);
}

  // just print the pressed key
   if (key == 'H' ){
    Serial.println(key);
     // step one revolution in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper4.step(512);
  delay(100);
}


  if (key == 'L' ){
    Serial.println(key);
     // step one revolution in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper4.step(768);
  delay(100);
  }


  if (key == 'P' ){
    Serial.println(key);
     // step one revolution in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper4.step(1024);
  delay(100);
  }


//---------DC_Motor---------

   delay(onTime);
  digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(IN3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);

 }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the [millis()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/)?

Comment: If you want to know how to use the `millis()` to avoid using `delay()` check the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example in the Arduino IDE. `File->Examples->02.Digital->BlinkWithoutDelay`.

Comment: In order to do several things simultaneously you need to get rid of the `delay()` statements and also of the `waitForKey()` statement.
Instead the Keypad library offers the possibility to add an event listener with the function ` keypad.addEventListener(keypadEvent)`.
Look into the example on the arduino page: https://playground.arduino.cc/KeypadTutorial/EventKeypad/

Answer (score 1):

The `delay(onTime);` statement in the `//---------DC_Motor---------` section of your code is preventing anything else taking place until the end of the DC motor run. Instead of delaying, you need to test how long the motor has been running, and do nothing if that time has not been reached yet. As others have pointed out, the BlinkWithoutDelay example program demonstrates how to do this. But in short, the motor section needs to do:

```
// Start motor here
timeMotorStarted = millis();
   :
   :
   :
if( millis() - timeMotorStarted > onTime ){  // has motor run long enough?
  // stop the motor
}
```